# more efficient way .php

Tags: php, performance, structure

i am using this code, but i know that is not very efficient.
There is another way? more efficient ?

```
  if ($val-> check($form) === true) {
        {$data['livre'] = $val-> validate_age($form);}

        if ($val->validate_age($form) === true) {
            {$data['livre'] = $val->insertData($db, $form, $id);}

            if ($val->insertData($db, $form, $id) === true) {
                {$data['livre'] = $val->insertLanguages($db, $form, $id);}

                if ($val->insertLanguages($db, $form, $id) === true) {
                    {$data['livre'] = $val->val($form);}

                    if ($val->val($form) === true) {
                        {$data['livre'] = $val->valexp($form);}

                        if ($val->valexp($form) === true ) {
                            {$data['livre'] = $val->insertWorker($db, $form, $id);}

                            if ($val->insertWorker($db, $form, $id) === true) {
                                {$data['livre'] = $val->univAndCourse($form);}
...
```

thanks

Comment: Not really if that's the logical flow and any *inefficiency* from a performance standpoint is trivial.

Comment: Why do you have {} outside the assignment statements?

Comment: did you mean this?   {$data['livre'] = $val-> validate_age($form);} ?

Comment: Yes. Also, aren't you calling the same function twice like this? Once for assignment, once in the next if()

Comment: Each one of your calls are done twice? Aren't you getting duplicate data?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by efficiency. If that solves your purpose, it's efficient. A suggestion though, you can put all the IF conditions that you have in a single IF statement using && operator. That will keep your code more clean and you don't have to perform the same task twice, first for assignment and then for IF. Alternatively, use can use `IF ($data['livre']) {` for all IFs other than first.

Comment: and i think that the problem is not totally clear. i need the return $error for each function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what [**exceptions**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) are for:

```
try {
   $data['livre'] = $val->validate_age($form);
   $data['livre'] = $val->insertData($db, $form, $id);
   $data['livre'] = $val->insertLanguages($db, $form, $id);
   $data['livre'] = $val->val($form);
   $data['livre'] = $val->valexp($form);
   $data['livre'] = $val->insertWorker($db, $form, $id);
   $data['livre'] = $val->univAndCourse($form);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   // 
   // Do what ever necessary to process the interrupted logic.
   //
}
```

Of course, this implies that methods of the validator class throw `exceptions` instead of returning `booleans`:

```
class Validator {

   function validate_age($form) {
      if (!is_numeric($form['age'])) throw new Exception('Invalid age.');
   }

   // 
   // .. etc ..
   //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could exit early.. I don't know exactly what's happening in your code when there's a failure, but if this would be in a function.. you could do instead of this:

```
if(condition1) {

  if (condition2) {

     return true;

  }

}

return false;
```

you could do:

```
if (!condition1) {
  return false;
}

if (!condition2) {
  return false;
}
return true;
```

So you basically handle the 'else' case first..

Besides that.. this may also work:

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3 && condition4) {
    return true;
}
```

or:

```
if (
     condition1 && 
     condition2 && 
     condition3 && 
     condition4
  ) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i need to check for each function the return $error, and stops the process.

Answer (score 1):

In this very specific case you could be able to compress it into an expression using  `and`  chaining:

```
$val-> check($form)
AND
    $data['livre'] = $val-> validate_age($form)
AND
    $data['livre'] = $val->insertData($db, $form, $id)
AND
    $data['livre'] = $val->insertLanguages($db, $form, $id)
AND
    $data['livre'] = $val->val($form)
AND
    $data['livre'] = $val->valexp($form)
AND        
    $data['livre'] = $val->insertWorker($db, $form, $id);
```

Which seems very appropriate since you really double assigments and `if` checks otherwise.

This works because `and` has a lower precendence than the `=` assigment operator. Your `===true` checks are certianly redundant. And if you wanted you could repackage that whole condition chain back as `if ()` predicate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all your function calls return a bool. This code should work. If any of the calls return false, $data['livre'] will be false.

```
$data['livre'] = $val->check($form) &&
                 $val->validate_age($form) &&
                 $val->insertData($db, $form, $id) && 
                 $val->insertLanguages($db, $form, $id) && 
                 $val->val($form) &&
                 $val->valexp($form) && 
                 $val->insertWorker($db, $form, $id) && 
                 $val->univAndCourse($form);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a function, turn all checks to negative and return from function, if the result is negative.
Additionally, you can use exception inside the $val methods, so you will interupt the execution whenever there is an error, without checking each operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could check all your validation in one outer conditional, open a database transaction inside of that.  Put all your inserts inside of a try and a transaction rollback inside of a catch.

something like this:

```
if ($val-> check($form) === true && $val->validate_age($form) === true && $val->val($form) === true && $val->valexp($form) === true) {
    //begin your transaction here.  Depending on your framework it could be different.
    mysql_query('start transaction');
    try {
        $val->insertData($db, $form, $id);
        $val->insertLanguages($db, $form, $id);
        $val->insertWorker($db, $form, $id);

        //... blah blah blah  more inserts here

        //commit your transaction here
        mysql_query('commit');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //Roll back the transaction here
        mysql_query('rollback');
    }
}
```

You just need to have your inserts throw an exception if they fail.